# Is it possible to use MSDN's LinkedList class to make a list where one parent node points to multiple children?

Tags: c#, linked-list, msdn

I'm trying to make a tree with C#. Many posts advise using a linked list, like the [LinkedList class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) that is a part of the .NET framework. But it seems like each MSDN LinkedListNode can only link to one child node (in that case the list would look like a line, not like the branching tree I'm shooting for). Am I missing something? There was another post on this, and people advised the poster to just build his own version of what seems to be called a multilinked list ( [How to create multiple nodes in a linked list then iterate through the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346384/how-to-create-multiple-nodes-in-a-linked-list-then-iterate-through-the-nodes) )

Is it time to cut loose from the mothership and try making my own tree? Should I make a new multi-linked node class that inherits from LinkedListNode?

Comment: A linked list is just that -- a list, a flat list. It can't represent a tree (although it could represent the list of an individual node's children, if for some reason you didn't want to use the more obvious `List<T>`). Where are you seeing recommendations to use a linked list for trees? And when you say "LinkedList class on MSDN", do you mean something different from `LinkedList<T>` that ships with the .NET Framework?

Comment: 1. that is what I mean by linked list on MSDN (edited question)   2. so don't use a linked list to represent a tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no trees in the standard class libraries.  You need to write your own, or find someone else's implementation that you can use.

I don't think you'd gain anything by inheriting from `LinkedListNode<T>`.  The semantics are different.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own Tree - http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/